# bc output binary as nibbles separated by whitespace

Tags: string, bc

I'm debugging code which contains quite a few bit shift operations, and I'm using bc a lot to look at what's happening on the bit level.

Here's what I use:

```
$ echo 'obase=2;598980975283696640' | bc
100001010000000000100000011000000011000000000111010000000000
```

Is there a simple way to get the output as whitespace-separated nibbles? E.g.

```
1000 0101 0000 0000 0010 0000 0110 0000 0011 0000 0000 0111 0100 0000 0000
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Edit: 
Thanks for the replies! However,

I tried it on another number,262148.

Should be:

```
100 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

But it is:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 100
```

I guess the script has to search backwards through the string to get it right?

Comment: Does it have to be in bc?  I would do something like...  echo 'obase=2;598980975283696640' | bc | while read -n4 a; do echo -n "$a ";done;echo

Comment: That should be an answer, already using pipes & bash, what's one more

Comment: bc is not required at all btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this simple function:

```
nibbles () { echo "obase=2; $1" | bc | rev | while read -n4 a; do echo -n "$a ";done | rev ; echo; }

$ nibbles 598980975283696640
1000 0101 0000 0000 0010 0000 0110 0000 0011 0000 0000 0111 0100 0000 0000
```

Comment: Tried it on another number,262148. 
Should be: 100 0000 0000 0000 0100
But it is: 1000 0000 0000 0000 100
I guess it has to search backwards through the string?

Comment: Okay, I believe I fixed that with rev.

Comment: That's just perfect. A thousand thanks to you :)

Comment: Shorter version with sed `echo 'obase=2;598980975283696640' | bc | sed -r 's/(.{4})/\1 /g'`

Comment: Note that that syntax is `bash` specific. Using `read -N4 a` would make it compatible with ksh (not zsh where it's `read -k4`, or other shells that generally don't have a similar feature).

Answer (score 7):

```
echo 'obase=2;598123123980975281233696640' | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc |
  rev | fold -w4 | paste -sd ' ' - | rev
```

Or:

```
echo 'obase=2;598123123980975281233696640' | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc | sed ':1
  s/\(.*[01]\)\([01]\{4\}\)/\1 \2/;t1'
```

`BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` is to stop `bc` from wrapping numbers at 70 columns. That's GNU specific though. `rev` is not a standard command, but quite common.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way would be to pad it to multiples of four:

```
echo 'obase=2;262148'| bc | perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = 0 x ((-length) % 4) . $_;s/([01]{4})/ $1/g;s/$/\n/'
```

Comment: Something like `sed ':a;s/\B[01]\{4\}\b/ &/;ta'` (which inserts spaces as required starting from the rightmost word boundary) should work even if the number of digits is not divisible by 4.

Comment: @steeldriver Which would be faster? Looping or reversing the text twice?

Comment: No idea! the sed loop is one I've come across before for inserting thousands separators (just needed to change the count from 3 to 4 and the separator from comma to space)

Comment: Your first command can produce a group with 1–3 digits on the right. The difficulty here is to get the incomplete group on the left.

Comment: @Gilles Isn't that what the second command does? I already contemplated reversing the output, but Stephane handled that and steeldriver the other method I could think of.

Comment: Ah indeed the second command does work.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you could use the python interactive shell for it. For example:

```
$ python
>>> s = bin(598980975283696640)[2:]; s = '0'*(4-len(s)%4)*(len(s)%4>0)+s
>>> [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
['1000', '0101', '0000', '0000', '0010', '0000', '0110', '0000',
 '0011', '0000', '0000', '0111', '0100', '0000', '0000']
>>> s = bin(5989809752836966)[2:]; s = '0'*(4-len(s)%4)*(len(s)%4>0)+s
>>> [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]
['0001', '0101', '0100', '0111', '1011', '0011', '0100', '0010',
 '1001', '0111', '0000', '1011', '0110', '0110']
```

Or for just one shot:

```
$ python -c 's = bin(598980975283696640)[2:]; s = '0'*(4-len(s)%4)*(len(s)%4>0)+s; print [s[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s), 4)]' 
['1000', '0101', '0000', '0000', '0010', '0000', '0110', '0000', '0011', '0000', '0000', '0111', '0100', '0000', '0000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply (GNU) `cut` to the output of `bc` using a custom output delimiter:

```
$ echo 'obase=2;5989809752836966' | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc | rev \
  | cut --output-delimiter=' ' \
     -c$(echo -n 1-4; for i in $(seq 5 4 100); do echo -n ,$i-$((i+3)); done ) \ 
  | rev
1 0101 0100 0111 1011 0011 0100 0010 1001 0111 0000 1011 0110 0110
```

The construction of the `cut` LIST supplied via `-c` exploits the fact that unused parts of that lists are not reported as an error.

A `dc` version:

```
$ echo '5989809752836966 2 o p' | DC_LINE_LENGTH=0 dc | rev \
  | cut --output-delimiter=' ' \
     -c$(echo -n 1-4; for i in $(seq 5 4 100); do echo -n ,$i-$((i+3)); done ) \
  | rev  
1 0101 0100 0111 1011 0011 0100 0010 1001 0111 0000 1011 0110 0110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'obase=2;262148' | bc |
   perl -E 'say readline 
                =~ s/((....)*)\n/ $1/r 
                =~ s/(\d{4})/$1 /gr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `bc` and `sed` do the splitting into nibbles for you, and use `bc` and `printf` to do the conversion to 0-padded 4-digit binary:

```
i=598980975283696640
echo "obase=16;$i" | bc | sed 's/./&\n/g' | \
  xargs -I {} sh -c 'echo "ibase=16;obase=2;{}" | bc' | \
  xargs printf "%04d "
echo

1000 0101 0000 0000 0010 0000 0110 0000 0011 0000 0000 0111 0100 0000 0000
```