# Store 2^500 in a variable in bash

Tags: bash, bc

I want to store the value of 2^500 in the variable `DELTA`.

I'm doing

```
export DELTA=$(echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc)
```

but this does not set `DELTA` to `3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376`. Instead, it sets it to

```
32733906078961418700131896968275991522166420460430647894832913680961\
33796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393\
053328527589376
```

I tried the answers in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12656/36325) (3 years old), using

```
export DELTA=$(echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc | tr '\n' ' ')
```

or

```
export DELTA=$(echo "scale=2; print 2^500" | bc | tr '\n' ' ')
```

but none of them work for setting the variable, only to echo it. Any idea?

Comment: try setting `BC_LINE_LENGTH` like Stephane does in this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176966/70524

Comment: You already got the answer(s), I only want to add that you don't need `echo` command. Instead use *Here String* redirection: `bc <<< "scale=2; 2^500"`

Comment: @jimmij One thing; going the `echo` way is much more portable (think commercial *nixes). Plus, you must ensure that your `/tmp` is __writable__ if you use here strings. Think of emergency consoles with `/` mounted __ro__ - your here string approach will FAIL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc | tr -d '\n\\'
```

Output:

```
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```

Comment: I though that tr works only with one char at a time ? oO

Comment: @StardustOne Not really. You can use arbitrary groups of characters with the two parameters, e. g. try `echo "havk vf sha" | tr 'fhaskv' 'sunfxi'` :) (this is rot13 for the poor man, with the chars deliberately unsorted to not give away the solution too soon :))

Answer (score 14):

In the GNU implementation of `bc`, there is the environment variable `BC_LINE_LENGTH` (cf `man bc`):

```
~$ echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc
32733906078961418700131896968275991522166420460430647894832913680961\
33796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393\
053328527589376
~$ export BC_LINE_LENGTH=99999 #or better 0
~$ echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```

Comment: I like this solution most, except that `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` does not work in my machine (Mac OS X), and I'm using really big numbers, so changing `BC_LINE_LENGTH` depending on the number is not enough for me. +1 in any case.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking outside the box:

```
export DELTA=$(python -c 'print(2**500)')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc | { read value; echo "$value";}
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "scale=2; 2^500" | bc | perl -pe 's/\\\n//'
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```